# make image has no touchable frame in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I want to add an image over a button. When I click on it, I will click on the button not the image. I tried to set an image for the button (beside its text), but I failed to resize it using this code. Please help me either write the correct code or to make an image over the button. It shouldn't block the button, which would annoy the user when the user wants to click the button below the image.

```
var img : UIImageView!
    img = UIImageView(frame:CGRectMake(0, 100, 0.10, 0.100));
    img.image = UIImage(named:"plus.png")
    createGroupButton.setImage(img.image , forState:  UIControlState.Normal)
```

Comment: i have tested many values for width and height but it doesn't change , when i change x and y it moves

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bharat's answer should work for you. However, in case you have an `image` which you want to place on top of any element and you want it to transfer touches to the elements behind it you need to set:

```
image.userInteractionEnabled = false
```

this also works for `UIView`s and for other subclasses of `UIView`.

Answer (score 0):

You can set UIButton's background image like this.

```
button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named:"plus.png"), forState: .Normal)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i said i want the image beside the button text , so , this won't help but thanks :D